# avm package is not installed when install Anchor on linux

Tags: linux, rust, anchor

I'm going to build solana smart contract with Anchor framework in linux.
So I have to install Anchor framework.
but error interrupt my way.
When I write avm install latest terminal order.
error is bellow.

````
  command 'gvm' from snap gvm (1.1.0)
  command 'vm' from deb mgetty-voice (1.2.1-1)
  command 'kvm' from deb qemu-kvm (1:4.2-3ubuntu6.23)
  command 'vam' from deb vim-addon-manager (0.5.10)
  command 'lvm' from deb lvm2 (2.03.07-1ubuntu1)
  command 'pvm' from deb pvm (3.4.6-2build2)
  command 'acm' from deb acm (5.0-29.2ubuntu1)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.```


please teach me how to fix this error.
````

Answer (score 0):

Anchor is probably installed correctly, but is not globally accessible. To check if avm is installed execute command: `cd ~/.cargo/bin` followed by `ls`. If u can see something like this: [directory list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UILwF.png)

then avm is installed correctly. The only step left is to make access to avm global.

To do so execute command `nano ~/.bashrc` and at the bottom of the edited file add line `export PATH="$PATH:<absolute-path-to-bin-directory-of-cargo>"`